# APPMAKER - Many to many relation is not working

Tags: google-app-maker

I am a little confused as to whether this is working properly, but I have made a many to many relationship between two tables. However unlike one to many relations, it does not seem to have created a field for this relation.

As such when I call it in the multi-selector, it comes up blank, as I am assuming that there is nowhere to write to?

I have also tried setting up prefetch on both tables, for each other, but this doesn't seem to have created the respective fields. Am I missing something?

EDIT:

1. At present I have no code
2. The situation is as follows:

I am trying to build an app for field agents to fill out when they are on the go. The way I am modelling the data is as follows:

Models:
1. Customer
2. Stores
3. Activities
4. SKUS
5. Field Agents

1. ONE Customer owns MANY Stores - Done
2. One Store can have Many SKUS. But Each SKU can belong to Many stores as well (Many to Many relation)
3. One Field Agent, can have many activies
4. One Store can have Many activities associated with it.
5. One SKU can have many activities associated with it.

The Issue:

When a NEW Store entry is created, I have a form that inputs:

Name
Location
What Customer it belongs to
What SKUS Are located in this store.

I am able to create the form, except for the last item. This is what I am refering to. How do I tell the app that Store X "owns" SKU A, B, C & D.

The reason I am doing it this way as well, is because later I want to be able to open an SKU page, and see a list of what stores it "owns".

I hope this clarifies things. I will try to post screenshots later, but I hope in the meantime this provides some indication of what I am attepmting to do. Alternatively I could share the applicatoin for you to have a look at it.

Comment: You can't get a field for a "Many relation" database. Imagine if there are a thousand related records. Putting all that info into a field makes no sense. You'll have to add a table with the datasource being the related records so you can view them, or a list or something similar.

Comment: But then how do I create the relations if there is no way to input it into a form? (Meaning how do I input the actúa related data)

Comment: I'd love to help here but I found your question too vague. Maybe if you are more specific, perhaps upload a couple of screenshots, show your code, etc... then maybe I could help a bit more.

Comment: Hi @Morfinismo I appreciate the enthusiasm! So let me try again.

Comment: If you can share the app, it would be better. I guess I kind of get what you mean so I'll try to work on an example.